# GA Search & Replace Filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I have the following URI in GA: /invite/accept-invitation/accepted/B

Which I'd like to change to: /invite/accept-invitation/accepted

I've tried a 'Search and Replace filter as follows:

**Search String -** /invite/accept-invitation/accepted/*

**Replace String -** /invite/accept-invitation/accepted

But the result I get is:

/inviteaccept-invitation/accepted/B

Could someone tell me where I've gone wrong with this please?

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics "Search and replace" filter uses regular expressions. More precisely:

> Replace string is either a regular string or it can refer to group
>   patterns in the search expression using backslash-escaped single
>   digits like (\0 to \9).

More details are available on the filter settings UI, which also refers to [this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en).

So in your case, the search string would be something like this.

```
 \/invite\/accept-invitation\/accepted\/\w+
```

In this expression `\` is escaped. Your last string part is captured with `\w+`, which 
matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]), between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

The Replace string doesn't have to be a regular expression. So in your case, your original version could be used:

```
/invite/accept-invitation/accepted/
```

Putting this together would result something like this, which gives the desired output in my test view:

[image]

Comment: Hi @kgrg. Many thanks for this. I'll give this a try and come back to you.

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi @kgrg. I've tested this, but unfortunately, it's not working. I still have the same outcome. Many thanks. Chris

Comment: Could you please check and edit (if needed), the sample URLs in your post? The result is not matching the sample and the RegEx. Is this a typo only in your post? Also, can you apply the suggested Search RegEx in your all pages report as a filter? Does it match your actual URLs?

Comment: Hi. Everything is correct in my original post. I actually don't see a reason why your solution doesn't work because it's quite simple, so it may be other filters that aree affecting this, so I close this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was referring to this part, which seems to miss a /: "But the result I get is: /inviteaccept-invitation/accepted/B". You are correct, filter order is important. Let me know, if there's anything I can add to help sorting this out.

Comment: No. There isn't a typo here. This is the value that is being returned. But I'll check the other filters. Regards

Comment: In this case, this can be one of the reasons, why the filter is not working as expected, as the search string contains an additional / compared to the result, and will not match.